# Enforcing order in Java Iterator

Tags: java, oop, iterator

I am providing a library for a different team. One of the methods I provide receives as argument an Iterator. I would like to somehow require a certain order of iteration. Is there any way to do this in code by extending Iterator?

Comment: As your receive the iterator and you *require* something, the requirement should at the least be stated in the documentation of your method.

Comment: Iterator can be from a collection that will or will not maintains order.

Comment: in addition to akaIDIOT you could check your order condition while iterating and throw an `IllegalArgumentException` if the order deviates.

Comment: If the Iterator provided is not in the order you desire, will you throw an exception, or will you reorder the elements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly. The iterator is made just to give you an item at time, avoiding to storing in memory and pass a whole list of values, which could be unfeasible at times.

Unless you have more knowledge on how the values are generated and which bounds have to be applied to the sorting of data, the only way is to get all elements from the iterator, store them in some list/vector/database, sort them and return another iterator using the sorted list.

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned above by akaIDIOT, I will state the requirement in the documentation. I'm still not sure whether checking the requirement and throwing an exception is a good idea. I won't store the elements in a list since my iterator is just a wrapper for a database ResultSet, which could potentially be quite large.

Answer (score 0):

You're being passed, as an argument, an instance of some concrete class which implements Iterator. You can't extend its class because its class is decided upon instantiation, which is done by the code that calls your method.

If you want to fail fast when the required order is not respected, try [Guava's Ordering.isOrdered() method.](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/snapshot-jre/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Ordering.html#isOrdered-java.lang.Iterable-)

NB This will only work if your argument is an Iterable, rather than Iterator. You need it to be Iterable (an interface which allows you to retrieve the Iterator) so that you can iterate twice: once to check order, once to process.